# I was running down the road trying to loosen my [load], I've got seven tags on my mind

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Actually, I only have three tags on my mind: [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load) tag, which I would like split into two separate tags.

On the face of it, the tag Wiki isn't too bad:

> A measure of the amount of work a computer is performing. CPU load is closely related too, but not exactly the same as CPU utilization.

This uniquely identifies a programming topic. Unfortunately, that doesn't really cover the possible meanings of the word, so the tag is widely misused. As can be expected, this tag is used not only for CPU load but also for loading files and a host of other topics.

On the plus side, this tag doesn't seem to be drawing a lot of off-topic or low-quality questions, so this'll mostly be a retag effort. Also, this tag does identify actual programming topics (it's just that it identifies several of them), so I'm not convinced that full burnination is justified here.

I propose splitting this tag into multiple tags, such as [file-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-load) and [cpu-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-load) (the latter of which already exists), to avoid confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: [The Eagles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagles_(band)) - *"Well, I'm runnin’ down the road tryin' to loosen my load. I've got seven women on
my mind."*. From *[Take It Easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfeNhwnO8hw)*. But [what does it mean](https://awesomelybadlyrics.blogspot.com/2009/10/eagles-take-it-easy.html)?

Comment: Love the song. Hate long subjects. How about `Let's unload [load]`?

Comment: Why not just, `Let's un[load]`?

Comment: Let's take a [load] off? This tag is over[load]ed?

Comment: I assume there's at least some mis-use of this combined with `[assembly]` for questions about load and store instructions, but that's a concept that doesn't need a tag.  Such usages should just be removed.

Comment: _, I've got burnination on my mind_

Comment: Let's give this tag a re[load]